# rasterFromXYZ() Error in rasterFromXYZ() : x cell sizes are not regular

Tags: r, ggplot2, raster, shapefile, r-sf

I am trying to plot points from a df (xyz/latlonvalue) as raster over a `geom_sf` shapefile. I tried the answers from another post but none of them helped. The data structure is below.

First I try `raster::rasterFromXYZ(df)` then the code from the answer on the other page but it does not work. I get the same error message from each attempt.

```
d <- structure(list(x = c(-87.001233, -87.416633, -86.999683, -86.58395, 
-86.998233, -86.998233, -86.998233, -86.998233, -87.416633, -87.416633, 
-87.416633, -87.416633, -87.001233, -87.001233, -87.001233, -87.001233, 
-87.001233, -87.001233, -87.001233, -87.001233, -87.001233, -87.001233, 
-86.58395, -86.58395, -86.58395, -86.58395, -86.999683, -86.999683, 
-86.999683, -86.999683, -86.916517, -86.965333, -87.233917, -86.721362, 
-86.916517, -86.916517, -86.916517, -86.916517, -86.916517, -86.916517, 
-86.916517, -86.916517, -86.916517, -86.916517, -86.766867, -86.766867, 
-86.766867, -86.766867, -87.233917, -87.233917, -87.233917, -87.233917, 
-86.965333, -86.965333, -86.965333, -86.965333, -86.721362, -86.721362, 
-86.721362, -86.721362, -86.721362, -86.721362, -86.721362, -86.721362, 
-86.721362, -86.721362, -86.721362, -86.37455, -86.37455, -86.37455, 
-86.37455, -86.37455, -86.37545, -86.967667, -86.766717, -86.72265, 
-87.2327, -86.37545, -86.37545, -86.37545, -86.37545, -86.37545, 
-86.37545, -86.72265, -86.72265, -86.72265, -86.72265, -86.72265, 
-86.72265, -86.72265, -86.72265, -86.72265, -86.72265, -86.72265, 
-86.967667, -86.967667, -86.967667, -86.967667, -86.967667, -86.967667, 
-87.2327, -87.2327, -87.2327, -87.2327, -87.2327, -87.2327, -86.766717, 
-86.766717, -86.766717, -86.766717, -86.766717, -86.766717, -87.001817, 
-87.416083, -86.582933, -86.9173, -86.9173, -86.9173, -86.9173, 
-86.9173, -86.9173, -86.9173, -86.9173, -86.9173, -87.001817, 
-87.001817, -87.001817, -87.001817, -87.001817, -87.001817, -86.582933, 
-86.582933, -86.582933, -86.582933, -86.582933, -86.582933, -86.99865, 
-86.99865, -86.99865, -86.99865, -86.99865, -86.99865, -86.99865, 
-86.99865, -86.99865, -87.416083, -87.416083, -87.416083, -87.416083, 
-87.416083, -87.416083, -87.00025, -87.00025, -87.00025, -87.00025, 
-87.00025, -87.00025, -87.00025, -83.9164, -82.915883, -82.452167, 
-83.9164, -83.9164, -83.9164, -83.9164, -82.417183, -82.417183, 
-82.417183, -82.417183, -82.417183, -82.417183, -82.417183, -82.417183, 
-82.417183, -82.915883, -82.915883, -82.915883, -82.915883, -82.452167, 
-82.452167, -82.452167, -82.452167, -82.983533, -82.983533, -82.983533, 
-82.983533, -82.983533, -82.983533, -82.983533, -82.983533, -82.783667, 
-82.340983, -82.783667, -82.783667, -82.783667, -82.783667, -82.06085, 
-82.06085, -82.06085, -82.06085), y = c(42.731083, 42.732717, 
43.132683, 42.733483, 42.380783, 42.380783, 42.380783, 42.380783, 
42.732717, 42.732717, 42.732717, 42.732717, 42.731083, 42.731083, 
42.731083, 42.731083, 42.731083, 42.731083, 42.731083, 42.731083, 
42.731083, 42.731083, 42.733483, 42.733483, 42.733483, 42.733483, 
43.132683, 43.132683, 43.132683, 43.132683, 43.599517, 44.759817, 
44.14175, 44.737115, 43.599517, 43.599517, 43.599517, 43.599517, 
43.599517, 43.599517, 43.599517, 43.599517, 43.599517, 43.599517, 
44.09025, 44.09025, 44.09025, 44.09025, 44.14175, 44.14175, 44.14175, 
44.14175, 44.759817, 44.759817, 44.759817, 44.759817, 44.737115, 
44.737115, 44.737115, 44.737115, 44.737115, 44.737115, 44.737115, 
44.737115, 44.737115, 44.737115, 44.737115, 45.178767, 45.178767, 
45.178767, 45.178767, 45.178767, 45.177783, 44.759917, 44.090067, 
44.73645, 44.139717, 45.177783, 45.177783, 45.177783, 45.177783, 
45.177783, 45.177783, 44.73645, 44.73645, 44.73645, 44.73645, 
44.73645, 44.73645, 44.73645, 44.73645, 44.73645, 44.73645, 44.73645, 
44.759917, 44.759917, 44.759917, 44.759917, 44.759917, 44.759917, 
44.139717, 44.139717, 44.139717, 44.139717, 44.139717, 44.139717, 
44.090067, 44.090067, 44.090067, 44.090067, 44.090067, 44.090067, 
43.1333, 42.733717, 42.733333, 43.60065, 43.60065, 43.60065, 
43.60065, 43.60065, 43.60065, 43.60065, 43.60065, 43.60065, 43.1333, 
43.1333, 43.1333, 43.1333, 43.1333, 43.1333, 42.733333, 42.733333, 
42.733333, 42.733333, 42.733333, 42.733333, 42.733083, 42.733083, 
42.733083, 42.733083, 42.733083, 42.733083, 42.733083, 42.733083, 
42.733083, 42.733717, 42.733717, 42.733717, 42.733717, 42.733717, 
42.733717, 42.383767, 42.383767, 42.383767, 42.383767, 42.383767, 
42.383767, 42.383767, 45.750033, 45.449183, 45.27775, 45.750033, 
45.750033, 45.750033, 45.750033, 45.516667, 45.516667, 45.516667, 
45.516667, 45.516667, 45.516667, 45.516667, 45.516667, 45.516667, 
45.449183, 45.449183, 45.449183, 45.449183, 45.27775, 45.27775, 
45.27775, 45.27775, 45.1371, 45.1371, 45.1371, 45.1371, 45.1371, 
45.1371, 45.1371, 45.1371, 44.761967, 44.453917, 44.761967, 44.761967, 
44.761967, 44.761967, 44.740467, 44.740467, 44.740467, 44.740467
), z = c(10.81, 10.84, 10.84, 0, 10.81, 10.89, 10.76, 10.86, 
10.89, 10.83, 10.88, 10.8, 10.79, 10.79, 10.8, 10.82, 10.78, 
10.78, 10.82, 10.86, 10.8, 10.83, 10.87, 10.87, 10.88, 10.88, 
10.83, 10.8, 10.81, 10.81, 10.8, 10.83, 0, 0.02, 10.8, 10.8, 
10.78, 10.79, 10.81, 10.8, 10.81, 10.82, 10.79, 10.81, 10.88, 
10.89, 10.9, 10.88, 10.77, 10.78, 10.77, 10.78, 10.84, 10.83, 
10.83, 10.84, 10.75, 10.77, 10.76, 10.77, 10.78, 10.79, 10.76, 
10.77, 10.79, 10.78, 10.78, 10.93, 10.94, 10.91, 10.95, 10.94, 
10.73, 10.79, 10.9, 0.01, 0, 10.8, 10.9, 10.83, 10.71, 10.75, 
10.75, 10.89, 10.89, 10.89, 10.77, 10.66, 10.68, 10.67, 10.6, 
10.71, 10.68, 10.67, 10.81, 10.73, 10.74, 10.73, 10.69, 10.69, 
10.73, 10.68, 10.67, 10.77, 10.81, 10.8, 11.09, 10.94, 10.72, 
10.78, 10.83, 10.82, 10.72, 10.8, 10.8, 10.73, 10.7, 10.68, 10.75, 
10.78, 10.75, 10.74, 10.77, 10.75, 10.68, 10.69, 10.67, 10.76, 
10.8, 10.74, 11.06, 10.89, 10.73, 10.7, 10.72, 10.71, 10.78, 
10.8, 10.78, 10.7, 10.63, 10.6, 10.72, 10.7, 10.71, 10.83, 10.82, 
10.75, 10.72, 10.77, 10.73, 0, 10.84, 10.84, 10.73, 10.6, 10.74, 
10.77, 6, 6.33, 0, 6, 6, 6.06, 6, 6.19, 6.24, 6.21, 6.21, 6.21, 
6.21, 6.21, 6.22, 6.21, 6.35, 6.34, 6.33, 6.33, 6.37, 6.36, 6.36, 
6.35, 6.05, 6.01, 6.04, 6.03, 6.04, 6.04, 6.07, 6.05, 6.02, 0, 
6.08, 6.09, 6.13, 6.08, 6.18, 6.18, 6.11, 6.14)), .Names = c("x", 
"y", "z"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -200L))
```

Comment: Can you include the actual code you used? You've only posed the data so far.

Comment: If you want to use geom_raster, you don't need to turn the data into a `raster::raster` first. (the problem with rasterFromXYZ might be that the grid spacing is not perfectly even - perhaps a rounding error - I've had that problem)

Comment: Your data contains only 30 distinct locations across the 200 rows, many of which are very close to each other and don't occur on a regular grid. You should check to make sure the x and y data hasn't been rounded or truncated somehow. Interpolating to a decent quality grid from this point data would be difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Your data do not look very regular. See `plot(d[,1:2])`.

Instead of `rasterFromXYZ` you can use `rasterize` in which case you specify the required geometry and then transfer the values to it.

Depending on your goals, you may also use `interpolate`